# Save array in model?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.3

I wanted to simply save an array of Strings in a model and later change it's value, but somehow the framework throws a nullpointer exception?
So how can I use an array in a model?

```
public String[] workinghours = new String[10];
```

Thats how I initialize the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            this.workinghours[i] = ("8-18");
}
```

And thats how I want to change the value later in a method.
But then I get an exception:

```
[NullPointerException: null]
```

But my array cannot be null?

Comment: You have to provide more information - the full stack trace, not only the exception; the place where it occurs; your model code, etc. Please also specify which Play version exactly are you referring to.

Comment: I think your model is wrong.